# Cannot assign to the result of this expression with generics

Tags: swift, generics, assign

I have the following generic class where I want to manage a string hash:

```
class NamedProfile<T> {
  private var set = [String:T]()
  private var profiles = [String]()
  private let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  private let profileName:String
  var currentSet = ""
  init(name:String, set:[String:T]) {
    profileName = name
    self.set = set
    if let existingProfiles = userDefaults.objectForKey(name) as? [String] {
      profiles = existingProfiles
    }
    for key in profiles {
      if let existingProfile = userDefaults.objectForKey(profileNamed(name)) as? T {
        set[key] = existingProfile // <-- error
      }
    }
  }
  private func profileNamed(name:String) -> String { return "\(profileName) \(name)" }
}
```

Why does the compiler croak in the above assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
init(name:String, set:[String:T]) {
    // ...
    set[key] = existingProfile // <-- error
    // ...
}
```

`set` refers to the (immutable) method parameter. 
Use `self.set` instead to refer to the property.

Comment: Ah! Sure. One of the pitfalls :-) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: One of the reasons I've maintained the habit of always using `self.`

Comment: I'll think about that. So far there were only few cases where I fell in that trap.